# Multiple NFC PN532 Using I2C interface with Raspberry

Tags: python

At first im only using 1 NFC PN532 and libnfc as the library, but when im trying to connect it to 2 same devices, it still gives the same address which is 0x24(because of libnfc). Since controlling it need unique address, i tried to find a way to change it. And i come to final answer which it is fixed address(hard code in the chip), to solve it i can only use raspberry gpio as additional bus but it only make the device connected to it limited. So i use another option that is to use I2C expander/multiplexer, the mux i use is TCA9548A. But now im wondering how to do this, any advice what should i do and how to do it?

Comment: Seems like more of a hardware question better asked on [raspberrypi stackex](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: oh, my bad ill ask there. Thanks sir